# how to estimate a ROC curve for a multinomial model

Tags: r

I want to estimate the ROC curve and the AUC of a model Multinomial Logistic Regression whit 3 levels. i have this code:

Y is:"1", "2" and "3"

```
model<-multinom(Y ~.,data = train)

predic1<-predict(model,newdata = test[,-1], type = 'prob')

library('ROCR')
pred  <-  ROCR::prediction(predic1,factor(test$Y))
plot(ROCR::performance(pred, measure="tpr" , x.measure="fpr"),
     xlab='False Positive Rate',
     ylab='True Positive Rate')
(AUC <- (attributes(ROCR::performance(pred, measure="auc"))$y.value[[1]][[1]][1]))
```

the line:

```
"pred  <-  ROCR::prediction(predic1,factor(test$Y))"
```

produces this error:

```
Error in ROCR::prediction(predic1, factor(test$Y)) : 
  Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.
```

any suggestion, it is possible to estimate the ROC curve for a Multinomial model.

Comment: was looking the same thing and this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/how-to-plot-roc-curves-in-multiclass-classification) may help